# How to make textview draggble from one LinerLayout to another?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, textview

Im developing android app for tower of hanoi.
I have used text view for making disks .
And I have 3 Linear layouts 
I want to make that textviews draggble and droppable to another layout

```
TextView mdisk1,mdisk2,mdisk3,mdisk4,mdisk5,mdisk6,mdisk7,mdisk8,mdisk9,mdisk10;

 mdisk1=findViewById(R.id.disk1);
    mdisk2=findViewById(R.id.disk2);
    mdisk3=findViewById(R.id.disk3);
    mdisk4=findViewById(R.id.disk4);
    mdisk5=findViewById(R.id.disk5);
    mdisk6=findViewById(R.id.disk6);
    mdisk7=findViewById(R.id.disk7);
    mdisk8=findViewById(R.id.disk8);
    mdisk9=findViewById(R.id.disk9);
    mdisk10=findViewById(R.id.disk10);
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please check . code added

Answer (score 0):

You should try first and submit the question along with your progress. I suggest you use library for dragging items. Here are some libraries you may use- 
https://github.com/justasm/DragLinearLayout
https://github.com/hyuwah/DraggableView

Comment: Hi there Im using the library suggested by you https://github.com/justasm/DragLinearLayout   but Im not able to move from one to another Layou   . It only makes it draggble into same layout

Comment: Why do you need to transfer to another layout?

Comment: I'm designing tower of hanoi game. Where 3 towers are placed in 3 different layouts . That's why

Comment: put them in a parent layout. use library to drag them into the parent library